# Splitting and rearranging in awk

Tags: awk

I don't have very much experience with awk. I have a list of names with phone numbers and other data.  I want to know how to rearrange the information to print by LastName, FirstName, other info.  This is how my file is currently arranged;

```
FirstName LastName:(510) 548-1278:250:100:175
```

See how last name is attached to the area code w/ no whitespace? So I can't do '{print $2 $1}' since that gives me the last name and the area code first.  I want it to look like;

```
LastName , FirstName (510) 548-1278:250:100:175
```

How do I split characters in a row?

Comment: Real names can contain spaces. In some countries two or more first and last names are very common. Having that, the input data can't be parsed automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you.

```
awk -F'[ :]' '{printf "%s , %s %s %s:%s:%s:%s\n", $2, $1,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' yourFile
```

Test:

```
$ echo "FirstName LastName:(510) 548-1278:250:100:175" | awk -F'[ :]' '{printf "%s , %s %s %s:%s:%s:%s\n", $2, $1,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}'
LastName , FirstName (510) 548-1278:250:100:175
```

Comment: Awesome thank you.  I am trying to understand it better though. so does '[ :]' tell awk to use a blank space and a colon for a separator? In regards to whitespace why does the blank space need to be before the colon?

Comment: @HillariDenny, Yes, awk to use both for a separator.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `sed`

```
echo "FirstName LastName:(510) 548-1278:250:100:175" | sed 's/ / , /;s/:/ /'
```

The first substitution `s/ / , /` inserting a comma when the first space is encountered.

The second `s/:/ /` substitution is replacing the `:` by a space.